# How to loop though user objects in django

Tags: python, html, django

I want to show all the user's Items.
Currently I can only show 1 object

**my_items.html** (where i want it to show)

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content%}
<main role="main">
        <div class="container">
          <!-- Example row of columns -->
          <div class="row">
            {% for item in item %}
                <!--{% if item.id == request.user.id %}-->
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <img style="max-width: 100px; max-height: 300px" src="{{ item.thumb.url }}">
                        </div>
                        <h2><a href="{% url 'items:detail' slug=item.slug %}">{{ item.name }}</a></h2>
                        <p>{{ item.snippet }}</p>
                        <p>{{ item.date }}</p>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-warning" href="#" role="button">Edit</button></a></p>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-danger" href="#" role="button">Delete</a></p>
                    </div>
                <!--{% endif %}-->
            {% endfor %}
          </div>
          <hr>
        </div> <!-- /container -->
      </main>
{% endblock %}
```

**views.py**

```
def item_myitems(request):
    item = Item.objects.all().order_by('date')
    return render(request, 'items/my_items.html', {'item': item})
```

I tried using filter() and get() on views.py

Comment: try change name of `{% for item in item %}` to `{% for item in items %}`. And same data in `def item_myitems` to `{'items': item})`. And you sure it have more than 1 object in `Item.objects.all()` ?

Comment: HTML comment has no effect on Django template tags. That `if` is working. Commenting on template level is `{# #}` or multiline https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#comment

Answer (score 1):

You should use a plural name to pass your items to your view:

```
def item_myitems(request):
    items = Item.objects.all().order_by('date')
    return render(request, 'items/my_items.html', {'items': items})
```

So you can distinguish one item from many items when you loop through them in your view:

```
{% for item in items %}
```

Comment: If you try in your function `item_myitems` to `print(len(items))` what does it print ?

Answer (score -1):

omg I got it working, i feel so dumb right now LOL
I uncommented my if in the html and set to this > {% if item.author_id == request.user.id %} i was comparing with the item id instead of the author_id

Comment: Those were HTML comments anyways, Jinja ignores them. You have to use `{# a comment #}` to make a comment in a template.